# Print only lines between curly braces from tail -f

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tail

I have a script that reads several debug logs, appends it to a temp file, then does a `tail -f` on the debug file so that we can monitor debug events in a single window and easily see when a user action induces an event.  There is a bunch of metadata also written to these debug logs that I don't want included in the monitor script's output.

Is there a way I can use `sed` or `awk` to print only data that's contained within curly braces (including the curly braces)?  The data within braces can, and always does, span multiple lines.

Data might look like this:

```
DON'T PRINT THIS DATA:!@#%$%^
DON'T "!@#()*& PRINT THIS DATA EITHER
}
DON"T PRINT THIS
{
PRINT THIS DATA BLOCK
AND THIS DATA
AND THIS LINE TOO:!@#(*&
}
DONT:!@# \/PRINT THIS
{
BUT PRINT THIS
}
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the output that's being parsed? A Bash-ism could do this without a separate process.

Comment: will `{` and `}` ever be present on the same line?

Comment: @jeremysprofile No.  The braces will always be on lines by themselves.

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward in sed. But we ask that you show your own efforts first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple sed

```
sed -n '/{/,/}/p' InputFile | sed '/^{/d' | sed '/^}/d'
```

Using Single sed

```
sed -n '/{/,/}/{/{/!{/}/!p}}' InputFile
```